# Access column value from relationship property

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Assume the following example where we have two `models` each referring to their respective `sqlite` tables:

```
class supplier_invoices(db.Model):
  id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  at_date =  db.Column(db.String(100))    
  at_shortnumber =  db.Column(db.String(100))    

  def __repr__(self):
      return str(self.at_date)

class product_inventory(db.Model):
  id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  pi_shortnumber =  db.Column(db.String(100))
  pi_lot_name =  db.Column(db.String(100))
  pi_at_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('supplier_invoices.id'),
      nullable=False)
  at_date = relationship("supplier_invoices")

  def __init__(self, id, pi_shortnumber):
    self.id = id
    self.pi_shortnumber = pi_shortnumber


@app.route('/pro_inv/')
def product_inv():
    return render_template('product_inventory.html', 
      product_query = product_inventory.query.order_by(product_inventory.pi_shortnumber.desc()).limit(20).all())
```

Then assume we are using the following `jinja2` template to display the `query` in a table form:

```
{% for pq in product_query %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ pi.at_date }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ pi.pi_lot_name }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ <!-- at_shortnumber --> }} <!-- ******* HOW TO GET SECOND COLUMN DATA HERE? -->
    </td>
    <td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see retrieving the first column data `pi.at_date` using `sqlalchemy` relationships is relatively straightforward. The resulting `jinja2` table displays `at_date` from the `supplier_invoices` child table along side the corresponding `pi_lot_name` column data from the parent `product_inventory` table it is joined with.

However, this `relationship` only returns the `at_date` column.

How would one go about retrieving the `at_shortnumber` column in the same `model` in order to display it along side the `at_date` column?

Obviously, one solution would be to create a new separate `model` relationship but this seems cumbersome to me since if one wants to retrieve let's say 10  columns we would have to have establish 10 separate `model` relationships.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to how to retrieve multiple columns' data from a related table using the same `model`? Or possibly a completely different way of achieving the same result?

Thank you in advance!

edit: additionally, how would one assign a parent name within the parent model class to the child column data so that one can manipulate the data directly from the model class? For example, if one wished to use : `concat = column_property(pi_shortnumber + "_" + pi_lot_name + "_" + at_shortnumber )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it as `pd.at_date.at_shortnumber`. From your code `pq.at_date` returns `at_date` value of the coressponding `SupplierInvoices` which is correct, what it actually does is `pq.at_date.at_date`. But you have it sharing names with `supplier_invoices.at_date` hence the confusion. Either change the column name for `supplier_invoices.at_date` or the relationship name for `product_inventory.at_date`.

Comment: Thx! Additionally if you can help with my edit above that would be very much appreciated.